# NP-hardness of sparsest cut

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Consider bipartitioning the vertices of a graph $(V,E)$ into $V = P \cup Q$ to minimize $$\frac{|E(P,Q)|}{|P| |Q|},$$ where $E(P,Q)$ denotes the set of edges in the cut.  The usual citation for NP-hardness is the paper

> Matula and Shahrokhi, Sparsest cuts and bottlenecks in graphs, Discrete Applied Mathematics, (May, 1990), Volume 27, 113–123.

However, the reduction in that paper from maximum cut proves NP-hardness for a generalization of the above problem where each edge can have a different capacity.  Where can I find a hardness proof or citation for the above sparsest cut problem for unweighted graphs.

Comment: I'm thinking this type of questions is more suitable to cs.stackexchange

Comment: The answers to this question on cstheory say a proof is in the textbook by Garey and Johnson: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/proof-that-sparsest-cut-is-np-hard

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my own question.  Usul, the thread you link to just mentions the same paper of Matula and Shahrokhi discussed in my post, which reduces a weighted version of sparsest cut to max cut, for which Garey and Johnson had proven NP-hardness. I haven't gone behind the paywall, but it looks like this recent paper below has the proof for the unweighted version:

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19222-7_14